# Physical significance of the discrete Heisenberg group

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, quantum-information, representation-theory, dirac-equation

In quantum mechanics, Schrodinger's position and momentum operators are characterized by the fact that they form a representation of the Heisenberg group $H_{2d+1}$ over $\mathbb{R}^{2d+1}$.

Discretizing this group, as did Weyl, gives a Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for all prime $p$, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Discrete_Heisenberg_group).
In the case $p=2$ this is the group generated by the Pauli matrices $\sigma_X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and  $\sigma_Z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

The same Pauli matrices happen to generate the algebra of observables for a spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particle.

Is this a pure mathematical coincidence? (If it is not a coincidence, then how does one mathematically distinguish the two situations?) Or is there a physical explanation for this observation that "discretizing the algebra of observables generated by position and momentum in continuous space gives the algebra of observables for a spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particle"?

Comment: I have to admit that I found the question hard to parse. Is the essence: "Mathematically, discretizing $\hat x$ and $\hat p$ (the algebra for continuous space) gives $\sigma_z$ and $\sigma_x$ (the algebra of spin-1/2 particles).  Is there an underlying *physical* reason for that?"  Did I guess this correctly?  (If yes, putting sth. like this at the beginning might help.) -- If there is, it would have to be a relativistic effect, since spin-1/2 only appears naturally (i.e. not ad hoc) in relativistic quantum mechanics. So a natural question could be whether these two things ...

Comment: ... are naturally intertwined in the Dirac equation, or maybe through Lorentz boosts.  (Is this along the lines of what you are looking for? Then clarifying this aspect and tagging it correspondingly might help to attract people who know more about relativistic quantum mechanics. Right now it sounds like it more about quantum computers, which certainly do not appear anywhere in my interpretation.)

Comment: Thanks. The quoted sentence is a good way to put it. Yes, I would like to know if this is a pure mathematical coincidence (and if it is not an entire coincidence, how to mathematically distinguish the two cases), or if there is a physical way to understand the coincidence. I'll edit.

Comment: If there were a deeper connection, then this would lead to the interesting follow-up question whether a corresponding connection also exists for $\mathbb F_p$. -- By the way, in some sense it is clear that these *are* physically connected, since spin-1/2 pops out naturally if you try to do relativistic quantum theory. I guess the question is more whether this physical connection between position and spin also gives rise to a connection between the different Heisenberg groups. One might wonder whether there is indeed a more general Heisenberg group acting on a spinor.

Comment: It is a coincidence to the extent that Weyl's ["QM around the clock"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#A_non-Hermitian_generalization_of_Pauli_matrices) with *p* "hours" parameterizes *U(p)* , and *SU(2)* covers the rotation group, thereby motivating spinors. If you expected "physical" analogs, e.g. for *p=3*, Sylvester's notions,  there aren't any, directly, but, of course, the mathematical structure is so robust it covers *SU(3)* of color and light flavor in particle physics, etc...

Comment: I think an interesting starting point would be to understand how the Lorentz group acts on spinors, and then how it acts on operators, i.e. general combinations of $x$ and $p$ vs. Paulis. It is well conceivable that such an action gives a natural extension of the Heisenberg-Weyl group.  Would something along those lines be what you are looking for?

Comment: That could help me form the right picture, yes. I don't know much relativistic quantum theory unfortunately. You write that "spin-1/2 pops out naturally if you try to do relativistic quantum theory." Can you help me understand this with a reference? Possibly a book chapter, and if possible not an entire book.

Comment: @ThomasVidick I feel that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation provides a pretty good (and reasonably concise) introduction in Section 1. Also, Section 3 (Lorentz covariance) seems to give something like what you might be after, when it relates $\sigma^{\mu\nu}$ (involving the Pauli matrices) and $J_{\mu\nu}$ (involving position and momentum).    (Note aside, please ping me with @[username] when responding in comments; the rules for who gets notified when - except the OP - are somewhat unclear; e.g. for your response above I did not get notified.)